# show() method makes fab wink

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button

I'm facing a weird problem with floating action button. I'm showing and hiding it based on recycler view scrolling. The problem is when I call `fab.show()`, the fab shows up and winks! Please help me solve this! Thanks.

[image: fab gif]

**code:**

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object: RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
         if (dy<0) {
            fab.show()
         }
         else {
            fab.hide()
         }
    }
})
```

Comment: you need to also check for it's visibility so it does not call the method .show() or .hide() without purpose. Check it out here http://thetechnocafe.com/how-to-hide-floating-action-button-on-when-scrolling-in-recycler-view/

Comment: @Traabefi it made no difference unfortunately